# Flutter application crashes on firebase phone authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am developing a flutter application in which I am trying to authenticate the user with Firebase Phone Authentication.

According to Firebase policy, we can't get Authentication code while debugging so I have to add my phone number to the firebase console with a predefined code.

Now It's working fine while debugging but when I use it in release mode when Google Play Services verified the phone, my application crashes. But when I open the app again it's authenticated and works fine. How do I debug this crash?

Here's my code

```
  signInWithPhone(String phone) {
    _authStatus = AuthStatus.Authenticating;
    notifyListeners();
    try {
      _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: phone,
          timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
          verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential _authCredential) {
            _getFirebaseUser(_authCredential);
            print("verificationCompleted: ${_authCredential.providerId}");
          },
          verificationFailed: (AuthException authException) {
            print("Auth Failed: ${authException.message}");
            _authStatus = AuthStatus.Uninitialized;
            notifyListeners();
          },
          codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) {
            this.verificationId = verificationId;
            print("Code Sent: $verificationId");
            _authStatus = AuthStatus.CodeSent;
            notifyListeners();
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
            this.verificationId = verificationId;
            print("Actual Code: $verificationId");
          });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }


  void _getFirebaseUser(AuthCredential authCredential) async {
    try {
      AuthResult authResult =
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential).catchError((e) {
        print(e.toString());
      });
      _firebaseUser = authResult.user;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      _authStatus = AuthStatus.Uninitialized;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can use Logcat to get the crash log

Comment: How do I get logs of a release application? It's not visible in debuggable apps.

Comment: you can filter but typing your bundle id in the search bar of logcat